# Is there a webpage which tells me when the next version of PHP is planned for release?

Tags: php

Before PHP 8.0.0 was released, I was eagerly awaiting it. It had an elaborate table detailed the planned release dates for the "GA" (final) version as well as all the betas/alphas/RCs. I unfortunately think this was just because it was a major new PHP version.

Now that I have tried PHP 8.0.0 and determined that it had a show-stopping bug, and reported that bug, and had it fixed, I'm eagerly awaiting 8.0.1 or 8.1.0 or whatever will be the next version of PHP.

Sadly, I've now looked through the entire PHP website without finding any such page.

Does it exist? PHP 8.0.0 was released "26 Nov 2020", so it seems like it could be due soon, but I want to know (roughly) when.

The mailing lists seem completely dead and offer zero clue into the PHP development/plans.

Comment: For those *"its ready when its ready"* cases, your best early warning may be watching upstream [VCS tags for release candidate tags](https://github.com/php/php-src/tags) (it might even have [an easier-to-parse atom feed](https://github.com/php/php-src/tags.atom)). Thats how I knew [what patches are scheduled for 8.0.1](https://github.com/php/php-src/compare/php-8.0.0...php-8.0.1RC1)

Comment: Generic solution, but not applicable here: Having your distribution hand-pick patches whenever their users care about certain bugfixes more than upstream cares about a swift release. Eventually, the package maintainer drops his patches in favour of a new *upstream* release - you might not even care/notice by that time. E.g. Debian&Ubuntu might have done this for major *show-stoppers* - had they already carried this version in a *stable/supported* release.

Answer (score 1):

Planning in opensourcesoftware projects is often whenever it is ready or necessary and you can only get notifications after the actual release.

Most open source projects maintain, arguably old-school , mailing lists and will often maintain an announcements list that is very low volume to announce the release of new versions and major events. See https://www.php.net/mailing-lists.php

The archive of the php announcement list doesn’t seem to contain a message of the 8.0 release though so that might not be the most useful to subscribe to anymore. https://news-web.php.net/group.php?group=php.announce

Otherwise: many open source projects use open development platforms that also non-contributors can follow and subscribe to. PHP uses GitHub which offers the option to subscribe and receive notifications whenever a new release is created there. See https://github.com/php/php-src/releases
Sign in —> watch —> custom —> releases